# Nearest Polygon to A point In Geopandas

Tags: geopandas

I have a point and I want to figure out which polygon is nearest to the point.
I have geo data of both points and Polygons.
[image: click for the image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`distance`](https://geopandas.org/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.distance.html) to find the distance to each polygon and sort them to retrieve the nearest.

#### Example

```py
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
>>> import geopandas as gpd
>>> d = {'geometry': [Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)]), Polygon([(3, 3), (4, 3), (4, 4)])]}
>>> gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d)
>>> red_point = Point(1,2)
>>> polygon_index = gdf.distance(red_point).sort_values().index[0]
>>> gdf.loc[polygon_index]
geometry    POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 1.00000 1.00000, 1....
Name: 0, dtype: geometry
```

*Note*: remember to set the CRS of the GeoDataFrame.

Comment: Is this the distance from the point to the centre of the polygon or the closest edge in the polygon?

Comment: `.sort_values().index[0]` can be shorten using `idxmin()`